# How can I fix the file when kernel dies?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to tensor flow and keras. When I try to combine matplotlib with keras and tensor flow, my kernel dies.
This is the code I have:

```
import numpy as np
import os
np.random.seed(42)

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=14)
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True, fig_extension="png", resolution=300):
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(fig_id, format=fig_extension, dpi=resolution)


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) =     keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000] / 255.,     X_train_full[5000:] / 255.
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]
X_test = X_test / 255.

print(y_train)
print(X_valid.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

# Multinomial logistic regression
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.summary()


model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",     optimizer="sgd", 
          metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, 
                validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))


import pandas as pd


pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1)
save_fig("learning_curves_plot")
plt.show()
```

My problem starts when I run the last 4 lines of code, where I want to plot the results. The kernel stops and dies automatically. The following is the message I get:

2023-05-07 11:16:49.401786: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-05-07 11:16:49.403200: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5 already initialized.
OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

Fatal Python error: Aborted

Main thread:
Current thread 0x000036b0 (most recent call first):
File "<**array_function** internals>", line 180 in dot
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2441 in get_affine
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2415 in transform_affine
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 1490 in transform
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 479 in transformed
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 2475 in get_tick_space
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 2083 in _raw_ticks
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 2144 in tick_values
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 2136 in **call**
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1484 in get_majorticklocs
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1262 in _update_ticks
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1413 in get_majorticklabels
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\core.py", line 741 in _apply_axis_properties
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\core.py", line 652 in *post_plot_logic_common
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\core.py", line 454 in generate
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib_*init**.py", line 71 in plot
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_core.py", line 975 in **call**
File "c:\users\frang.spyder-py3\tutor\spyder\f06_mnist.py", line 94 in 
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 469 in exec_code
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 611 in _exec_file
File "C:\Users\frang\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 524 in runfile
File "C:\Users\frang\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2248\1988908460.py", line 1 in

Restarting kernel...

I would really appreciate some help with this error since it happens also with other files. Is it a problem with the instalation of the packages? What should I do?
Thank you everyone for your time and effort

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Francisco Gonzalez, Which tensorflow and python version have you installed in your system? The above mentioned code is not showing any error in Google Colab and Jupyter notebook (python 3.10 , Tensorflow 2.12). Please check if you have installed tensorflow, matplotlib and pandas package in your system correctly. You can try again uninstalling matplotlib `pip uninstall matplotlib` and reinstall it using `pip install matplotlib`(restart the kernel ). Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help! I was able to solve this by uninstalling all the packages. It was a problem regarding the installation of one of the packages.